# Bootstrap: create 2 dropdownlist from typeahead with nextall()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've got this code from bootstrap: [link](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/4024).

Apparently it creates 2 kinds of dropdownlist from typeahead using nextall(), but I don't understand how to implement this. Do I need to change something in the bootstrap typeahead file?

**Text from link:**
*Exposed typeahead render method so you can override it and customise the list html based on the type of object returned from a custom source. You need this if you want to produce something like the new twitter search/autocomplete.
Changed .next() to use .nextAll(':has(a):first') so you can have separating result types.
Example*

```
var labels
  , mapped
$("input").typeahead({
  source: function (query, process) {
    $.get('/autocomplete', { q: query }, function (data) {
      labels = []
      mapped = {}

      $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        mapped[item.label] = item.value
        labels.push(item.label)
      })

      process(labels)
    })
  },
  render: function () {
      var that = this

      items = $(mapped).map(function (i, item) {
        i = $(that.options.item).attr('data-value', item)

        if (item.thumb) { // Ok object has a thumbnail.
          i.find('a').append(''+that.highlighter(item));
        } else {
          i.find('a').html(that.highlighter(item))
        }

        return i[0]
      })

      items.first().addClass('active')
      this.$menu.html(items)
  },
  updater: function (item) {
    return mapped[item]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement the commit you linked (which, it seems, has since disappeared from the Bootstrap source), you can download [gcoop's modified version of bootstrap-typeahead.js](https://github.com/gcoop/bootstrap/blob/ed0830c7d7efd7337b8b4fb35b98e51a0229d762/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js) and use that instead of the original.
Note that his fork was on version 2.0.4 and may cause issues if you're using a newer version.